# how to create executable jar using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar, executable-jar

Hi i am new comer to develop Swing application using Eclipse IDE.
I am using java sdk 1.7 with Ubuntu 12.04 Operation System. also using Eclipse IDE Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1).

when i try to create executable jar with following steps -
1- Save project properly.
2- right click project and click export.
3. click on java tag
4. click on Runnable Jar files
5. export jar file successfully. after searching concept at google.

Whenever i open this file window 7 operating system environment then
a  error is being displayed

```
could not find the main class <class name>. program will exit.
```

**I have checked main class .MF file. class is exist. why this error is being displayed ?.**

```
public class Start {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Start window = new Start();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Start() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel lblHiIaM = new JLabel("Hi i am a example");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblHiIaM, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

}
```

This code is run successfully in IDE.
I need to create a installable exe file of project.

Please help me if possible. 
i am very sick.
Thanks

Comment: Have you chosen proper Launch configuration?

Comment: How does it look created MANIFEST.MF file?